# Your `pubspec.yaml` file does not contain a `flutter_native_splash` section

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How can I solve this here is my `pubspec.yaml`

[image]

Comment: move `flutter_native_splash` from `dev_dependencies:` to `dependencies:` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem - I deleted spaces:

- between `color` and `:`
- between `image` and `:`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There could be something wrong with the formatting of your `pubspec.yaml`. Here is a working one:

```yaml
name: test_app
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  # Use the correct version for your app, here I use `any` for demonstration
  flutter_native_splash: any 
  
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#42a5f5"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

You can try pasting your other package in this template, or use another method guided in [the package's documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash), which is to create a `flutter_native_splash.yaml` file at the project's root:

`flutter_native_splash.yaml`'s content

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#42a5f5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the space between **flutter_native_splash:** and **create**.

The right command is this one: **flutter pub pub run flutter_native_splash:create**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Follow the below code at pubspec.yaml file,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.17

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#42a5f5"
  image: "assets/splash_logo.png"
```

Step 2: Run the 'flutter pub get' command on the terminal.

Step 3:  Run flutter pub run flutter_native_splash: create

[image]